# Query Return Null while apply where clause on Embeddable object

Tags: hibernate, hql, embeddable

Hello EveryOne,

```
 @Entity
    public class Parent {

        @EmbeddedId
        private Child child;

        @Column(name = "TEST")
        private long test;

       getter setter

    }
```

and chlid class

```
@Embeddable
public class Child {

    @Column(name = "TEST1", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String test1;

    @Column(name = "TEST2", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String test2;

getter setter and hasCode and Equal function 
}
```

There are model with Embeddable Composite Key.

```
String hql = "select v from Parent v WHERE v.child.test1= abc";
        List<Parent> list2 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(hql).list();
```

and this is query.

if i am put where clause on child.test1 then it will return null,null as record.but if i am remove a where clause then it will be map fine with Parent.

Please Help me.

Comment: It should work if `abc` is a proper value which matches some record in database. Can you turn on SQL logging to see the query that actually goes into database?